# Dual 9500GT video cards, one works

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I have two video cards, both are PCIe 512MB Nvidia 9500GTs. One is an Evga and the other is another brand.

If I put them both in, the one in the top slot will work (either card). The one in the lower slot says Code 12, not enough resources to use this device. I've tried disabling Firewire and a few other things in an attempt to get more "resources".

Intel DP45SG motherboard. 4G Ram. 64bit Vista. Q8200 CPU. I do not have the SLI connector.

Answer (score -1):

I read somewhere that for some mainboards you can try with 2GB RAM instead of 4GB, that may fix it. Perhaps the memory space is too full for 4GB plus two video cards on your mainboard.

Comment: If I understand right, you're conflating system memory and Video Memory